# Searching for python modules containing non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, search, character-encoding, module, ascii

I have a Python project containing hundreds of modules. In Python 2.6, the encoding of source files (modules) must be ASCII unless
an explicit encoding declaration is present. Is there a simple way to find out which python modules contain non-ASCII characters? So that I can correct them.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [chardet](http://chardet.feedparser.org/) python package. You can use the same `os.walk` approach as agf and call the `chardet.detect` method and flag files that are not ASCII (or with a lower confidence value).

This does leave some room for error though, so if you wanted to be more sure, you could also scan each file for characters that are unlikely to appear in a python file (non-alphanum, non-punctuation, etc). However, this will not detect things like UTF-16 chars that have the same value as two 7-bit, zero padded ascii chars i.e. `U+16705` <--> `AA`.

That said, if the characters that you want to exclude are from a limited number of character sets, you should be able to locate them with high confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Not very speedy, but it would work. It will work for any ASCII compatible encoding, such as UTF-8, Latin-1, etc. but not for UTF-16.

```
def find_non_ascii(packagedir):
    for filepath in os.walk(packagedir):
        if not filepath[-1].endswith('.py'):
            continue
        filepath = os.path.join(*filepath)
        for line in open(filepath):
            for char in line:
                if ord(char) > 127:
                    yield filepath
                    doublebreak = True
                    break
            else:
                doublebreak = False
            if doublebreak:
                break
```

or

```
def find_non_ascii(packagedir):
    for filepath in os.walk(packagedir):
        if not filepath[-1].endswith('.py'):
            continue
        filepath = os.path.join(*filepath)
        try:
            open(filepath, 'rb').read().decode('ascii')
        except:
            yield filepath
```

Edit: This second version is probably faster.

Comment: I think the `ord(127)` test will only exclude extended ascii chars.  There's an intersection between the set of char values in multibyte encodings and the value of two sequential 7-bit ascii chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
open(filename).read().decode("ascii")
```

If that raises a UnicodeDecodeError, you have some non ascii chars in there

As Dana says, this is not enough to guarantee that the file isn't UTF-16 or similar